# Bundle NPM package that connects to applications store

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, redux, package

I've been fighting with webpack and loosing for the last day and a half and I give up, please help!

So what I'm trying to do is create an NPM package that will be used in many of our sites. We have multiple sites with a shared functionality, we are using redux and I have made an npm package that provides actions, reducers and middleware that can be imported across multiple projets. That works great, no worries there. I am now trying to make a second package that contains components that use the main application's state from the redux store.

This second package uses selectors and dispatches actions provided by the first package.

- I wrote the component in the main application, works great,
- I created a new project for the second package, copy and pasted the component, it's scss module file, added the first package and other dependancies as peer dependancies
- built with webpack (after some troubles with peer dependancies not being found, I had to install them with install-peers, maybe this has something to do with my problem)
- I then npm installed the package in the main application... and I'm getting "store is undefined".

I think there is a problem with my webpack config, somehow the component doesn't seem to have access to my application's store as if it exists in its own little world. This is my guess, I could be miles off.

We are using react, next, redux and scss modules.

Here is my webpack config (externals are commented out as I'm using peer-deps-externals-webpack-plugin):

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
var path = require("path");
var PeerDepsExternalsPlugin = require('peer-deps-externals-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve("build"),
        filename: "index.js",
        // libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
        library: 'mm-chat-components',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'styles.css',
            chunkFilename: 'styles.css'
        }),
        new PeerDepsExternalsPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.module\.s(a|c)ss$/,
                loader: [
                  MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                  {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                      modules: true,
                      sourceMap: false
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                      sourceMap: false
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
                exclude: /\.module.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
                loader: [
                  'css-loader',
                  {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                      sourceMap: false
                    }
                  }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    externals: {
    //     react: "react",
    //     reactDOM: 'react-dom',
    //     mmTheme: 'mm-theme',
    //     mmChatRedux: 'mm-chat-redux',
    //     mmReduxBase: 'mm-redux-base',
    //     redux: 'redux',
    //     reactRedux: 'react-redux',
    //     finalForm: 'final-form',
    //     reactFinalForm: 'react-final-form',
    //     twilioChat: 'twilio-chat'
    }
};
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mm-chat-components",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build-webpack": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "mm-redux-base": "git+https://github.com/MMTSURVEY/mm-redux-base.git",
    "mm-theme": "git+https://github.com/MMTSURVEY/mmj-theme.git",
    "final-form": "^4.18.7",
    "react-final-form": "^6.3.5",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "twilio-chat": "^3.3.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "mm-chat-redux": "git+https://github.com/MMTSURVEY/mm-chat-redux.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^5.2.6",
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules-sass": "^1.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "install-peers": "^1.0.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "peer-deps-externals-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.4",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

And my babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

I'm generally lost when using webpack, it still seems like magic that's far beyond my comprehension.
That's lots of info, I hope it's all clear! Thanks in advance for any help! You guys rock.

Beau